Is it possible to consume a .NET Standard 2.0 WCF Service using ASP.NET Core 8.0 client application?
As a step to upgrade to .NET Core, we have upgraded our .NET framework provider library from .NET 4.8 to .NET Standard 2.0.
Now we are trying to consume this WCF service provider in the client using the web.config bindings and endpoints specified in our old client.
Every time we try to do something like that we get an error

Configuration not supported.

The service refers to a wsdl file and creates a reference file. Our goal is to consume the existing web.config file with endpoint & binding to consume the service in client.
Any help will be appreciated.

Please try to migrate the binding and endpoint configuration in web.config to the code to ensure that the program can access the WCF service normally.
